# tmobile arduino attachGPRS

Tags: arduino, gprs, xively

I am trying to connect to Xively using a SIM900 GSM shield and using the library that arduino has provided to do so. I have an Arduino UNO R3 with me. I have tested the sim card is registered with the network using another dev kit and sending text msgs from it.

The settings that I use are as follows:

```
#define GPRS_APN       "epc.t-mobile.com"  // replace your GPRS APN
#define GPRS_LOGIN     ""     // replace with your GPRS login
#define GPRS_PASSWORD  ""  // replace with your GPRS password
```

This is for tmobile. I even tried ATT go phone sim card and changed the APN but its still the same.

```
#define GPRS_APN       "phone"  // replace your GPRS APN
#define GPRS_LOGIN     ""     // replace with your GPRS login
#define GPRS_PASSWORD  ""  // replace with your GPRS password
```

However when I try to run the setup part of the code:

```
    while (notConnected)
    {
    if ((gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY) &
        (gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD) == GPRS_READY))
      notConnected = false;
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
```

the code doesn't move ahead from the gprs.attachGPRS part. I am not very sure but I believe there is no login and password on my GPRS setting. My network provider contact did not give me any such details.

Is there a default setting that I am missing out?

Any help provided will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

-n

Answer (score 1):

Your network provider is maybe in this list : [gprs list](http://ftp.icpdas.com/pub/cd/usbcd/napdos/3g_modem/gtm-201-3gwa/manual/gprs_apn.pdf)

---

For T-Mobile USA : guest guest

---

For T-Mobile UK : user pass